# Don't have to articulate hataras nedarim?

Tags: pronunciation, beit-din-court, speech-talking, nedarim-shevuot, motzi-yedei-chovato

I recently made a hataras nedarim in which two of the three dayanim were not articulating a single word, but simply intoning something like a low hum, during the part that is supposed to be said simultaneously by the three dayanim. One dayan, meanwhile, was saying the text. This is probably a basic question, but what is the explanation for why I was still yotzei -- as I'm sure I was?

Comment: My guess would be that their "low hum" was actually their recitation of the text. My experience from synagogue is that some people who quickly recite words they have said countless times sound like they're humming when in fact they are - hopefully - saying many distinct words.

Comment: @Jay, sounds like an answer. Perhaps post it as such?

Comment: @Jay I was standing a few feet away from them and their lips did not seem to be moving at all. I could be wrong.

Comment: @SAH If you have a question about the procedure of the Beit Din, you should, with respect, ask them. Just tell them that you don't understand. I am sure they will be happy to teach you about what was going on.

Comment: I'm curious, myself - regarding Hatarat Nedarim, I wonder if it may require 3 dayanim to hear the case but it is sufficient for just one of them to verbally annul. This sounds similar to what occurs in, say, civil cases. You have a panel of judges. They reach a majority decision. But just one of them announces the verdict.

Comment: See Yoreh De'ah 228:1. If a person is an expert *Chacham*, he can go to just one person. Offering benefit of doubt, here, perhaps the person reciting the verses qualified as such?

Comment: @DanF Oh, ok. That actually might be why! I don't know exactly what level of expertise is necessary, but the people sitting on this beis din were serious talmidei chachamim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The barebone Halacha is in Yoreh De'ah 228 -  [סימן רכח - דיני התרת נדרים](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_31.html#HtmpReportNum0025_L2) - where it says that all that the 3 people need to say is מֻתָּר לָךְ - preferably thrice.

So I'm not sure what the others were saying but as long as they said מֻתָּר לָךְ (or similar, in any language) even once, the hataras nedarim is valid.

My guess: They either say it often and were zipping through it, or they had no clue why they need to say more than מֻתָּר לָךְ and were mumbling to make it look good.

> **ג:** **כֵּיצַד הִיא הַהַתָּרָה? יֹאמַר לוֹ** (ה) **ג' פְּעָמִים: מֻתָּר לְךָ**, אוֹ שָׁרוּי לְךָ, אוֹ מָחוּל לְךָ, **בְּכָל** (ו) **לָשׁוֹן שֶׁיֹּאמַר**, (בֵּית יוֹסֵף בְּשֵׁם הָרַמְבַּ''ם), וַאֲפִלּוּ מְעֻמָּד, וּבִקְרוֹבִים, וּבַלַּיְלָה...‏
>
> **באר היטב**  (ה) ג' פעמים. ובדיעבד **סגי בפעם א'** (אלא עושים כדי לחזק הענין) וכ''כ הב''י והב''ח בשם הרמב''ם דא''צ שיאמר רק פ''א ש''ך:‏
>
> **באר היטב** (ו) לשון. פי' אפילו בלשון לע''ז מחילה והתרה אבל אם אמר מופר לך או נעקרה שבועחך וכיוצא בזה לא אמר כלום שאין מיפר אלא הבעל והאב הרמב''ם:‏

Comment: While I see that your citation **seems** to say that all 3 people should recite this, I am curious if that's required, or even *bedi'eved* it suffices for one person to say this.

Comment: @DanF, if you look there you will see the rules of a single Chacham being able to do it himself, and it seems we can't do this nowadays, in general.

Comment: Based on @SAH's profile picture and other questions, they should be saying מֻתָּר לָךְ, not לְךָ

Comment: @Heshy - Changed לְךָ  to לָךְ when not quoting sources. :-)

Comment: @DannySchoemann Why do all three people need to say it? If the court decides to annul the vow, couldn't just the head of the court report the decision?

Comment: @DoubleAA - is he "reporting" or is he "annulling"? If the latter, maybe you need the entire court to agree - i.e. do it together. IDK - I need to research this further.

Comment: Can you emphasize where it says that all three do the saying? What you quote says, in my translation: "How is the _Hatarah_ [done]? **He** says to him 3 times ... in any language that **he** may say ..."